# jQuery selector when a table is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table (generated at run time) and a dropdown. Before the page is up, the table does not exist. Once the page is up, the table and the dropdown look [similar to this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jscriptor09/c4ejzzL7/3/):

```
$("#aDropDown").val($("WhatToPutHere?").text());
```

I am trying to do the following: when the user select the Select button, I need the dropdown selected item to match the Type for the row.

Any example would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: You need to take action on some event. As it is, you're running code at page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you have multiple button with the same id. They should share a class.

```
<button class="aButton">Select</button>
```

next, what you want is the `.text()` of the prev `<td>`

```
$('.aButton').on('click', function() {
    var type = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
    $("#aDropDown").val(type);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/c4ejzzL7/6/)
as @Mackan pointed out, you might encounter a problem if you're not using a 
delegated event, as you're creating the table dynamically. in that case the following code would work better :

```
$(body).on( 'click', '.aButton' , function() {
    var type = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
    $("#aDropDown").val(type);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... all responses pointed same direction.  thanks to all.   One question :   if I have 7 columns and I am looing for the value in col 3, is there a way to reach the value in the column 3 with less rev chaining?   var tagType = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').text();

Comment: @jscriptor I want to stress the info about *delegated events* in my answer (not a plug to get accepted, by all means stick with this as *answer*)

Comment: What if the table structure change? I don't want to be rude but this might not be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.aButton').click(function(e) {
  var btn = $(e.target);
  $("#aDropDown").val(btn.data('category'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <td>item</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Action</td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="anItem">Apple</td>
    <td class="aType">Fruit</td>
    <td>
      <button class="aButton" data-category="Fruit">Select</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="anItem">Orange</td>
    <td class="aType">Fruit</td>
    <td>
      <button class="aButton" data-category="Fruit">Select</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="anItem">collard</td>
    <td class="aType">Veggie</td>
    <td>
      <button class="aButton" data-category="Veggie">Select</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>aDropDown:
<select id="aDropDown">
  <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
  <option value="Veggie">Veggie</option>
</select>
```

Removed id attribute from each button (id should be use for unique elements).

Added aButton class to each button.

Answer (score 1):

As I said above, your code must run on some event. Here's how I'd do it with minimal markup changes (just a class on the buttons):

```js
$('.selectBtn').click(function() {
  var myVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('.aType').text();
  console.log(myVal);
  $("#aDropDown").val(myVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>item</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Action</td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="anItem">Apple</td>
    <td class="aType">Fruit</td>
    <td>
      <button id="aButton" class="selectBtn">Select</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="anItem">Orange</td>
    <td class="aType">Fruit</td>
    <td>
      <button id="aButton" class="selectBtn">Select</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="anItem">collard</td>
    <td class="aType">Veggie</td>
    <td>
      <button id="aButton" class="selectBtn">Select</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>aDropDown:
<select id="aDropDown">
  <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
  <option value="Veggie">Veggie</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Would be useful if you tell him where to put this click listener, since he's asking about a dynamically created table.

Comment: True. I missed that point. The accepted answer covers it well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said your table is created dynamically, you should use a bind to a persistent element, using a *delegated event* (like document or body):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

All of the other answers (time of writing) uses binds that will add the event handlers to the actual buttons. This means that if the button doesn't exist, or gets temporarily removed, the bind will be lost or can't be created to start with.

Using a delegated event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.aButton', function() {
```

or..

```
$('body').on('click', '.aButton', function() {
```

Also notice that the above binds use a class selector, `.aButton`, because **id's must be unique** (and yours were not).

```
<button class="aButton">Select</button>
```

Full example [at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4ejzzL7/7/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.aButton', function() {
    $("#aDropDown").val($(this).parent().prev('td').text());
});
```

Edit:
If the table structure is in danger of changing (adding more td's or tr's), the below script will be better at finding the *correct* td (by class `.aType`):

```
$(document).on('click', '.aButton', function() {
    $("#aDropDown").val($(this).closest('tr').find('.aType').text());
});
```